# Jquery Multiple Select Show values in <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display the value of all my select fields in a list (li).

Here is my HTML code.

```
<select name="is_format" id="is_format">
   <option value="A4">{l s='A4'}</option>
   <option value="A3">{l s='A3'}</option>
</select>
<select name="is_color" id="is_color">
   <option value="Couleur" selected>{l s='Couleur'}</option>
   <option value="Noir/Blanc">{l s='Noir et Blanc'}</option>
</select>
```

Thank you

Comment: what did you try so far? why there is {} ? do you use any framework?

Comment: Really? Replace `select` by `ul` and `option` by `li`.

Comment: your reputation is going to be reset, deleting this question may gain back as it was before.

Comment: OP should include what has been tried or demo at most..if you dont want to be downvoted to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like,

```js
var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');

function createList() {
  ul.empty();
  $('select option:selected').each(function() {
    li = $('<li/>').text($(this).text()).attr('value', this.value);
    li.appendTo(ul);
  });
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
  createList()
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="is_format" id="is_format">
   <option value="A4">{l s='A4'}</option>
   <option value="A3">{l s='A3'}</option>
</select>

<select name="is_color" id="is_color">
   <option value="Couleur" selected>{l s='Couleur'}</option>
   <option value="Noir/Blanc">{l s='Noir et Blanc'}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code works except that it adds my 2 values ​​while I have to select 1 and when I want to replace this value it adds more rows

Comment: See my updated answer..

Comment: Thank its good with this :)